# Store class data in an array in swift 4 that is not modifiable

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I am creating characters and want to store them in an array. The problem occurs when I want to store the second character, because it overwrites the data of the first one - it seems like the variable is stored instead of a mirror of the content:

Code in Playground:

```
import UIKit

class character {

    var name: String
    var owner: String

    init() {
        name = "Frodo"
        owner = "Ben"
    }
    func random() {
        name = "Gollum"
        owner = "Hans"
    }
}

var CharacterArray: [character] = []

let testchar = character.init()

CharacterArray.append(testchar)

testchar.random()

CharacterArray.append(testchar)
```

---

When I look into the first appended array, ("Frodo, Ben") is stored. When I look after the second append both entries are ("Gollum", "Hans").

How can I ensure that the data stored in the array is an individual value? I believe I have a conceptional error here.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the problem of Swift 4, but the difference between reference and value types in Swift. You can change your `character` from class to struct, and you will see the difference.

```
struct MyCharacter {
    var name: String
    var owner: String

    init() {
        name = "Frodo"
        owner = "Ben"
    }

    mutating func random() {
        name = "Gollum"
        owner = "Hans"
    }
}

var myArray: [MyCharacter] = []

var csVal = MyCharacter()
myArray.append(csVal)
csVal.random()
myArray.append(csVal)

for character in myArray {
    print(character.name)
}
```

One more thing is you should capitalise the first letter of the Class/Struct name and change the first letter of your variable name to lower case. Check [this](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) out for more information of Swift name conventions.

---

If you still want to keep your design, a work around is to return a new `Character` from your `random` function.

```
import UIKit

class Character {
    var name: String
    var owner: String

    init() {
        name = "Frodo"
        owner = "Ben"
    }

    init(name: String, owner: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
    }

    func random() -> Character {
        return Character(name: "Gollum", owner: "Hans")
    }
}

var characterArray: [Character] = []

let testchar = Character()
characterArray.append(testchar)
let random = testchar.random()
characterArray.append(random)

for character in characterArray {
    print(character.name)
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the amazingly fast help! Using "struct" instead of class solves the issue!   My reference code which was programmed in swift 2 though had the character defined as "class" (but I cannot execute the code anymore because too much has changed!).

Comment: I updated my answer in case you want to keep your design, but depending on your goal it should be improved anyway.

Comment: Another thing is your should also take a look at the naming conventions in Swift for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. The real code does not need a random function, it catches the entries from a database in a loop so that is why it always uses a constant with the same name. I adjusted my code to the naming convention as well. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: In this case, using `init(name: String, owner: String)` in the loop to initialise a new object every time with different name and owner will be helpful. Btw, please marked your question as answered if it tackles you problem.